# Why use absolute paths for Django's static and template directories?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I don't understand why they want us to use absolute paths when we try to add static directories in django. I mean, these two work exactly the same:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
```

as this :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

simply keeping it as `'static'`, keeps things simple. So, why absolute path? I want a new answer to this, because there are older answers, but those are for quite old versions of django.

Comment: What older answers have you found? What do you think has happened in Django since then to change that advice?

Comment: Well older answer's links don't work! :P But, the crux of the argument was portability. I don't see why that is a problem, since I've tried it on both windows and linux, and have had no problems.